# ajax doesn't work on rails 3.2 with production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

everyone.

I created a new project and scaffold.
When I execute rails server with 'RAILS_ENV=production rails s', ajax seems not to work.

> rails new testpro
>
> cd testpro
>
> rails g scaffold User name:string email:string
>
> rake assets:precompile
>
> RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
>
> RAILS_ENV=production rails s

And I added one record, then go back to index page.
I can see the record and show, edit, destroy link.
As I click the destroy link, it just show the record.
It seems that the link work get request.

It should popup confirmation of delete.

Webrick reports following message.

> Started GET "/assets/application-f79f879edae5d837e15161fba0ee9d3d.js"
> for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-31 14:02:12 +0900
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
> "/assets/application-f79f879edae5d837e15161fba0ee9d3d.js"):

Actually, I encountered same problem with other project and try to clarify the problem with a plain project.

My environment is as follows:
Rails 3.2.3
ruby 1.9.3p125
sqlite3

Other project:
Rails 3.2.0
ruby 1.9.3p125
MySQL
Apache2 + Passenger

Yusuke.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm running into the same problem where my ajax:success callbacks aren't fired in production but work fine in development. Why would I need to enable `config.serve_static_assets`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you simply have not precompiled your assets

```
rake assets:precompile
```

By default, in production mode, the gems needed for asset compilation are not loaded, and it is assumed that assets have been precompiled into files from which they can be served up with maximum speed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But as I cited, I did precompile assets.

Answer (score 0):

config.serve_static_assets = true in production.rb worked fine for the new project.

As for my project, I modified application.js and my project worked fine.

brefore:

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery  
//= require jquery_ujs
```

after:

```
//= require jquery  
//= require jquery_ujs  
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```